# Julia codegeneration with global function

Tags: julia

julia 0.5.1

I want to create a function inside a quote that can be used after the specified macro has been used. Here is an example of what I mean

```
macro wat()
  quote
    type Foo end
    global bar() = begin end
    global function bar2()
    end
    type Baaz end
  end
end

@wat
Foo()
Baaz()
bar()
bar2()
```

Now when I run this the last line crashes, because bar2 is undefined. I do not understand why because in my understanding bar() and bar2() should be equal and bar is just syntactic sugar for bar2. But they are apparently not equal and I do not understand why the one works and other does not.

Secondly is there a way to define bar and bar2 inside that quote without the global-keyword and still being available after the macro has been executed?

My motivation for wanting the bar2 notation is that I can specify a return-type with this syntax.

```
global bar3()::Void = begin end
```

Is not allowed syntax.

Comment: Because of macro hygiene (https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/metaprogramming/#hygiene), names of local variables in the returned expression are replaced with unique symbols. Therefore, you need to use `esc` on symbols or expressions with local variables that should be left alone. However, I am not sure why `global` does not work for `bar2`. Use `macroexpand(:(@wat))` to see the generated code.

Comment: The macroexpand shows me that some kind of symbols have been added to the bar2-function it looks like this `global function #3bar2()...` the `bar()` function does not have that kind of stuff around it. But how do I prevent julia from adding some crap around my function?

Comment: @tim Putting esc around the quote does the trick, if you want you can answer. Otherwise I will answer myself tomorrow with your answer ;)

Comment: Unrelated to the question, when you say *crashes* it suggest a system exception taking down Julia with it - very bad. It is better to say the last line gave an error, or threw an exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the returned expressions of Julia macros, names of local variables are replaced with unique symbols:

```
julia> macro foo()
        quote
            x = 1
            global y = 2
        end
    end
@foo (macro with 1 method)

julia> macroexpand(:(@foo))
quote  # REPL[1], line 4:
    #1#x = 1
    global y = 2
end
```

This feature is called [macro hygiene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro) and avoids accidental clashes with variables at the call site.

To escape from this behavior, one has to use `esc`:

```
julia> macro bar()
                quote
                    x = 1
                end |> esc
            end
@bar (macro with 1 method)

julia> macroexpand(:(@bar))
quote  # REPL[1], line 3:
    x = 1
end
```

Often, one doesn't want to escape the whole returned expression but only specific parts of it:

```
julia> macro myshow(expr)
        quote
            x = $(esc(expr))
            println($(string(expr)), " = ", x)
            x
        end
    end
@myshow (macro with 1 method)

julia> x = pi/2
1.5707963267948966

julia> macroexpand(:(@myshow sin(x)))
quote  # REPL[1], line 3:
    #1#x = sin(x) # REPL[1], line 4:
    (Main.println)("sin(x)", " = ", #1#x) # REPL[1], line 5:
    #1#x
end

julia> @myshow sin(x)
sin(x) = 1.0
1.0

julia> x
1.5707963267948966
```

For details, I recommend to read the [corresponding section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/metaprogramming/#hygiene) in the manual.